# How to use SMOTE effectively in below case?

Tags: python, sampling, random-forest, oversampling, smote

I have an imbalanced multiclass data set, where I am trying to apply SMOTE to synthesis data for minority class. The problem is, for many classes, I have only 1 sample. Even when I try to tackle it with `k_neighbors=1`:

```
oversample = SMOTE(random_state=0, sampling_strategy=low_occurance_dict, k_neighbors=1)
X_class_train, y_class_train = oversample.fit_resample(X_class_train, y_class_train)
```

It shows this error:

> ValueError: Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples, but n_samples = 1, n_neighbors = 2

How to solve this problem?

N.B. the `y_class_train` here is not exactly class label in true sense. This is an id, which works like a customer group in my data. And I want to have same amount of entries from each group, and trying to blow the minority groups with SMOTE.

Comment: I don't understand why it would give such an error but try creating a `NearestNeighbors` instance with `k=1` and pass it (to SMOTE) as the `k_neighbors` parameter.